# Can I unify the style of facebook sign in button like Google in android app?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, authentication

I'm making the app with the sign-in system. But I want to unify the style of each button. My activity_login.xml show what I'm using the widget. I want to apply the Google button style to 'continue with Facebook'.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/login_sign_google"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is just add these buttons in to layout, make their `visibility` - `GONE` and add custom buttons with whatever you want styling.

And on click just pass click event like this:

```
    loginFacebookStyledButton.setOnClickListener {
                loginFacebookActualInvisibleButton.performClick()
     }
```

With google sign in I dont think that you need to have `SignInButton` simple styled button does the job.